Style.css and .js files doesn't load at first - load only after forced reload
So I made a wordpress theme, everything works ok on localserver. Updloaded it to a webserver and here is the problem: neither style.css or any of the .js files I've made load. The console returns this error:
(6) Mixed Content: The page at '' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet ''. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
1 of the 6 similar errors:
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://mywebsite.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://mywebsite.com/wp-includes/css/dist/block-library/style.min.css?ver=6.5.3'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
(8) Mixed Content: The page at '' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script ''. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
So, same error for stylesheet and scripts. Only the html structure and it's images are loaded, but no styles applied, no scripts loaded.
BUT after a single forced reload (ctrl+shift+R), everything loads normally. I have no idea what might be the problem. Thanks in advance for any helpers :)

It would be helpful if you shared the section of code where you're loading any stylesheets or scripts that are causing the issue.
